# WPF dynamically add button + function

Tags: c#, wpf

I wanted to ask you. I am writing a WPF program where I had a problem and had to ask you for advice. How can I dynamically add a button to a WPF window? Again, how can I assign the value of button_click inside the button by giving it a function. Thanks everyone in advance

Comment: Is it just one button you're going to add? Have you considered starting ofc with it defined in xaml and disabling, hiding or collapsing the button when whatever it does is inappropriate?

Comment: Adding a small code snippet of what you've tried and explaining what you need to change can help people give specific help for your individual situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Content = "some text"
//set other properties in a similar way
b.Click += (sender,e) => {/* your click handeler*/}
container.Children.Add(b);
```

where `container` is a `Grid` or something similar that you want to add your button to.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps below.

```
private void SomeEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Your code here        
}

Button newBtn = new Button(); //Initialize the button object

newBtn.Content = "Name"; //Give the poor button some text

newBtn.Click += SomeEvent; //Add a click event handler. It is a function which the button will perform when clicked.

MainGrid.Children.Add(newBtn); //Now add the button to your container. It could be a grid panel, stack panel or any other container.
```

You can also apply padding or margin to further control how the button appears. But that's optional. Cheers!